# Jqtouch mobile phone turn

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am trying to listen for a turn event on my device

```
$('body').bind('turn', function(event, info){
alert(info.orientation);
console.log(info.orientation); // landscape or profile
});
```

This event only gets fired once at the start. How do i get it to keep listening?

Answer (score 0):

after your inclusion of jquery mobile framework:

```
 $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
   alert(jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation()); 
 });
```